# MPV media player rotate video problem in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, mpv-media-player

I rotate videos in MPV media player with a keyboard shortcut.
To add the rotating feature through the keyboard, I need to add:
`tab cycle_values video-rotate 90 180 270 0` in `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`. So, now, if I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the video rotates.

The problem is that I rotate the video but the content gets cut off by the screen. Please see the below pictures:

1. Default video screen when I open the video file:

   [image: Default video screen]
2. When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate the video:

   [image: player after pressing Tab once]
3. When I re-press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate the video:

   [image: player after pressing Tab twice]
4. When I re-press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate the video:

   [image: player after pressing Tab thrice]

As you can clearly see in screenshots 2 and 4, the video content gets cut. This is problem which only happens in Kubuntu. I have tested this in Ubuntu and Windows, no issues there.

Comment: Drag the window up? Or maximize it?

Comment: Yes, I can drag up. But this not a perfect solution. I have to drag for every time when I rotate.